# Will debugging damage my battery?

Tags: battery, charging, usb-debugging

I work as a Android developer and I use my own phone for debugging as well as some other devices. Keeping the phone connected with USB will automatically charge my phone but will my battery be damaged by being connected 8~ hours at night and 8~ hours at work every day?

Comment: Well, I don't think so because if I talk about modern smartphones they have IC in place which cuts down the power intelligently and over USB I would say it's pretty much less voltage when compared with charger. So, nope I don't think it would damage your battery !

Comment: There are provisions to stop overcharging etc etc, but it will keep the temperature of the battery up, and temperature is the single worst enemy of a battery (outside of something unusual like a fire, explosion, water etc), so I would imagine it will degrade the life of the battery. They have a limited number of charge/discharge cycles, so the fact it is charging to full, depleting a few % and charging again all day won't help. How much effect it **actually** has; I don't know.

Comment: I have used my Nexus 4 for developing and personal usage for about a year and no problem so far.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/3623727/5778786 to debug wirelessly.